# Animation duration of UICollectionView on deletion of cell in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uicollectionview

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

  NSArray* itemPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

  [self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:itemPaths];

  [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:tempArray

  } completion:nil];
```

I want to Increase or Decrease the duration of Animation of cell delete
But I am not able to find any way to do this task

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{

                         NSArray* itemPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

  [self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:itemPaths];

  [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:tempArray

                     } completion:nil];
```

The above code of UIView animation do not work for UICollectionView

Is there any way to accomplish this task of changing the animation duration of UICollectionView cell delete ???